# What are the parameters of a tefillas shov (unnecessary prayer-request)?

Tags: tefilla, mistakes, publications

What are the parameters of a tefillas shov (unnecessary prayer-request)?

Someone is waiting for blood test results. He prays and asks Hashem that the results should indicate good health. Is this a tefillas shov if he prays when:

1] blood taken but not yet analysed.

2] blood analysed, results printed but not yet communicated to the patient.

How does this fit with the sayings of Chazal

> אין הברכה מצויה אלא בדבר הסמוי מן העין
>
> A blessing is only found in
>   something concealed from the eye (Bovo Metzi'a 42a)

Even the prayer of case 2 might be allowed because the results have not reached the eye of the patient.

> הרי זו תפלת שוא היתה אשתו מעוברת ואומר יהי רצון שתלד אשתי זכר
>
> If his wife were pregnant and he said, "May it be His will that she
>   has a boy" that is a tefillas shov. (Mishnah Brachot 54a)

Maybe even the prayer of case 1 would be a tefillas shov because the state of the blood is now determined even though not tested.

Comment: I don't understand what prayer you refer to.

Comment: The implication of "I promised to 'Thank Hashem' when the results came back as negative for both tests." is that he prayed that the results come back negative and then he will 'Thank Hashem'.

Comment: See Mishnah Brachot 54a

Comment: But he did not actually give a prayer. He promised to thank Hashem for the results. That is different.

Comment: Edited the question - thanks for the comments!